# How do I setup my static appharbor with php post support?

Tags: php, forms, email, appharbor

I have created a simple html based website hosted on appharbor and wants to add a form that visitors can completed and then send the information by email using php.

I have gathered some php scripts for sending the mail and have also created the form, when I test the page on my computer (without php installed) I can enter information and press "Send" and then I'm transfered to the php page which I feel seems correct.

The problem is when I deploy this at appharbor, I can enter the information in the form but I when I press the button to send the mail I either get a 404 error stating that the page is missing or I get the information that the HTML verb is unsupported.

Do I need to create some web.config file even if it otherwise is a static html site?
Do I need to activate something on my site or at appharbor?

--- Update ----

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="test.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<div id="legend">
<legend class="">Request</legend>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" id="email" email="email" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">                    
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="name">Your name</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
<button class="btn btn-success">Skicka</button>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

php script file

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {

$email_to = "something@mail.ma";
$email_subject = "Message from homepage";

function died($error) {
  echo "Error occured please correct. ";
  echo $error."<br /><br />";
  die();
}

if(!isset($_REQUEST['name']) ||
   !isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
  died('Something was wrong, please correct.');       
}

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$email_message = "Message.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

Thanks for the request

<?php
}
?>
```

I've removed some of the form as well as some error testing in the script that I normally have.

Comment: This is the error I get if I'm using Post method instead of Get.    405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

Comment: provide more information, post your code (main php file)

Comment: Updated the question with code from the form and php script